# Why is my navigation menu working at any page size on Windows and Mac computers but not on iPad and Android phone?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

I have made a Web site as a favour for a someone. The general code will likely disappoint but it's been done this way as it has to work on some niche, legacy technology.

Anyway, it works well enough, except we've discovered an issue with the menu. You can drag and resize the window on a Windows or MacOS desktop computer and it works as desired, switching to the ubiquitous three-bar mobile menu when the window gets small enough. However, it doesn't work at all on either my iPad or Android phone. This kind of navigation is new to me as I took a multi-year break from Web development, so I may be missing something laughably obvious.

Any ideas?

The development site is at: http://rcomp.michaelstubbs.uk

The CSS is in this file:

https://rcomp.michaelstubbs.uk/stylesheet.css

The navigation code included on each page is in this text file:

https://rcomp.michaelstubbs.uk/titlebar.txt

I was going to paste in only the relevant code but it occurred to me that maybe there's something I don't think is relevant but is, so just linked to the files instead.

Comment: You should try to put  code direct into your question to show the problem as when the external sites either get mended or disappear this question will be useless to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, the CSS responsiveness functionality stops at (720px). Targetting max-width of 720px means the responsiveness will only work on screen sizes below 720px and not above that, if you want the responsiveness to work on iPad then increase the max-width size to iPad size which is (768px) or more.

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
.topnav.responsive .icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've implemented that so it changes at the right point.

The responsiveness works. But if you load the site in a mobile or iPad browser, and tap on the three-line menu icon, it highlights the icon but no menu drops down. That's the big issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're welcome. I didn't notice that earlier, this might be related to using the "onclick" function directly on the link where there's a hover state. It's advisable to target the element instead and create an event listener. I have run the code locally and it works on mobile and desktop. I hope it works for you too.

```
 //your head tag should look like this
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>RComp | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">   
</head>

 //JS
<script>
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
     // Select the menu icon element
     var menuIcon = document.querySelector('.icon');

     // Add a click event listener to the menu icon
     menuIcon.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Select the navigation element
        var nav = document.getElementById("myTopnav");

        // Toggle the responsive class
        nav.classList.toggle("responsive");
     });
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: You should use [`Element.classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) instead of manually altering the class attribute.

Comment: Thanks once again, Beth. I still get the same result on mobile here - just highlights the menu icon and that's it, both on iOS and Android. When you say the code runs locally, do you mean as in your suggestion works within my existing code/pages when downloaded and run on your machine?

Comment: Yes, I copied your code and ran it locally on my machine, the new code should work. I hope you removed the old click function ( myFunction() ) from the link tag.

You can check it out on Codepen and compare the code: https://codepen.io/beth-codes/pen/BaEzZqZ

Comment: I just checked your website now and the problem is the old function; change this (        <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>) to this (<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon">&#9776;</a>). 
The "myFunction()" is not needed anymore since we are using an event listener.

Comment: Hi Beth. Thanks very much for looking at this again. It's still not responding in mobile at all, and there's now a () next to the logo in the top-left. I guess I was naive to think I could get away with copy-pasting a solution in from a Web site after a quick Google search! I'm wondering if there's something fundamentally wrong with this menu and it would therefore be best to rip it out and change to another, but as I say, my Javascript knowledge is pretty much zero so I wouldn't know what's causing it all.

Comment: Hi, I just realized you didn't include a meta tag. Include this line into your head tag <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">